# installing two qmail on same linux

Tags: linux, email

I want to installing two or more qmail on same linux server.Is this possible? If it's possible how can I do that?

Actually I want to send mails from the different domain names and different IP addresses.For instance;

```
xxx@a.com > 11.11.11.11
xxx@b.com > 22.22.22.22
xxx@c.com > 33.33.33.33
```

If it's not possible, what's your recommendation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible, although pointless. QMail can handle different domains just fine. (see http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#virtual-domains ) Nevertheless, if you definitely want multiple instances I would suggest to chroot them. (And provide *different* /etc/hosts to them!)

Answer (score 0):

If your only requirement  is for each domain to use a different IP to send emails there is no need to install different instances of QMail.

I would highly recommend to use JMS's combined [patch](http://qmail.jms1.net/patches/combined-details.shtml) that has this functionality as well as a number of other enhancements.

Once you have that the functionality controled is by the control/senderip file in the form

```
domain:1.2.3.4
```

Any mail sent from an email address from that particular domain will be sent from the given IP address.